# How to add additional zero arrrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have the following problem in my simulation.

`A` is an array `24 x 2`. I am going to split it and get 4 or 12 array.  It means that I group 6 or 2 array. It will be ok, if I use even "split" coefficient. If it is odd, I can"t split `A`.[ I can't group 5 or 7, because of 24/5=4*5 + 4 ( or 5*5 -1)  or 24/7=7*3+3.

That's why I going to do the following:

If I have `24  x 2` and need group every 5 together:

```
block 1 : A(1,:), A(2,:),A(3,:),A(4,:),A(5,:)
block 2 : A(6,:), A(7,:),A(8,:),A(9,:),A(10,:)
block 3 : A(11,:), A(12,:),A(13,:),A(14,:),A(15,:)
block 4 : A(16,:), A(17,:),A(18,:),A(19,:),A(20,:) 
block 5 : A(21,:), A(22,:),A(23,:),A(24,:), ?
```

As you can see the 5th block is not full, Matlab gives me an error. My idea is to create A(25,:)=0. For my simulation it will be ok. 
I am going to simulate it as `function`:

```
A=rand(m,n)
w- # number of a vector that i would like group together ( in ex., it is `5`)
```

```
if mod(w,2)==0
   if mod(m,2)==0
       % do....
   else 
       %  remainder = 0
   end
else
    if mod(m,2)==0
       %  remainder = 0
   else 
       %do...
   end
```

I was going to simulate like above, but then I have noticed that it doesn't work. Because 24/10 = 2*10+4. So I should write something else

I can find the reminder as `r = rem(24,5)`. As an example above, MatLab gives me `r=4`. then I can find a difference `c= w-r =1`  and after that, I don't know how to do that.

Could you suggest to me how to simulate such a calculation?

Answer (score 2):

Determine the number of blocks needed, calculate the virtual amount of rows needed to fill these blocks, and add as many zero rows to `A` as the difference between the virtual and actual amount of rows. Since you didn't mention, what the actual output should look like (array, cell array, ...), I chose a [`reshaped`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) array.

Here's the code:

```matlab
m = 24;
n = 2;
w = 5;

A = rand(m, n)

% Determine number of blocks
n_blocks = ceil(m / w);

% Add zero rows to A
A(m+1:w*n_blocks, :) = 0

% Reshape A into desired format
A = reshape(A.', size(A, 1) / n_blocks * n, n_blocks).'
```

The output (shortened):

```
A =
   0.9164959   0.1373036
   0.5588065   0.1303052
   0.4913387   0.6540321
   0.5711623   0.1937039
   0.7231415   0.8142444
   0.9348675   0.8623844
   [...]
   0.8372621   0.4571067
   0.5531564   0.9138423

A =
   0.91650   0.13730
   0.55881   0.13031
   0.49134   0.65403
   0.57116   0.19370
   0.72314   0.81424
   0.93487   0.86238
   [...]
   0.83726   0.45711
   0.55316   0.91384
   0.00000   0.00000

A =
   0.91650   0.13730   0.55881   0.13031   0.49134   0.65403   0.57116   0.19370   0.72314   0.81424
   0.93487   0.86238   0.61128   0.15006   0.43861   0.07667   0.94387   0.85875   0.43247   0.03105
   0.48887   0.67998   0.42381   0.77707   0.93337   0.96875   0.88552   0.43617   0.06198   0.80826
   0.08087   0.48928   0.46514   0.69252   0.84122   0.77548   0.90480   0.16924   0.82599   0.82780
   0.49048   0.00514   0.99615   0.42366   0.83726   0.45711   0.55316   0.91384   0.00000   0.00000
```

Hope that helps!